# PHP statement: while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have troubles to understand the use of

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

to display some elements of a database that are in the variable "$query".
Moreover, I dont understand what is passed to the variable "$row" by the function "mysql_fetch_array()".
My guess is that only one record (or row) of the database records that are in "$query" is given, but how does the function know which row??

I'll try to explain myself using an example.

Assuming I have 3 records in the variable $query with two fields (say "id" and "name").
At the first while the variable $row is filled by the first element (say id=1, name=antonio), then some code allow me to display or manipulate "1" and "antonio", then the code ends and the while starts again.

Now I assume that what is given to the variable "row" is the second element, but how does the function knows that must return the second element (and not the first one or the third one)?? I mean, I dont give this information anywhere...

Comment: actually, you execute a query that returns a result , and you loop the result until you've read all data

Comment: `$query` is a _result resource_. It does not contain data, but serves as a link to the RDBMS and the query you just performed. `mysql_fetch_*()` instruct the RDBMS to get the next row and return it as an array into `$row`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable $query is a resource and as such, has some sort of internal "row counter". Every time you call mysql_fetch_array() or a variant thereof, this counter gets incremented. As a result, every time you call this function mysql_fetch_array, you get the next row. When the last row has been received, and you call it again, it returns false. Because of the way a while loop works, you break out of this loop.

Answer (score 2):

If you place the statement `$row = mysql_fetch_array()` as your while loop's conditional statement you will accomplish two things:

1. You will get a new row of MySQL information that you can print out each time the while loop checks its conditional statement.
2. When there are no more rows the function will return FALSE causing the while loop to stop!